# dynamic href using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, href

Is there a way to create a dynamic href using radio buttons?

```
radio = value1
radio = value2
radio = value3

<a href="test.php?value=radio">
```

Comment: If you want to submit form data — use a form and a submit button! If you want three things to click on to go to different places — use three links! Don't try to mix links and form controls, build on stuff that works: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder what are you trying to do, however you can:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
       $('a').attr('href', 'test.php?value' + $(this).val()).text($(this).val()).appendTo($('body'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot^^
Is it also possible with radio button and checkbox combined?

Comment: @Xin: You are welcome, yes you can do with checkboxes too, just change the radio name at line $('input[type="radio"]') with checkbox.